# How can I show an "email-id already exists" message in React.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How do I show an 'email-id already exists' message using React.js?

I have checked the 'email-id already exists' condition in the back-end. But I don't understand how to show that message near a textbox.

I have tried to show the message in an alert.

Here is the registration form:

```
    var RegistrationForm = React.createClass({
        //get initial state enent
        getInitialState : function(){
            return {
                strFullName : '',
                strEmail:'',
                strPassword : '',
                Fields : [],
                intPhoneNumber:''
            }
        },
        // submit function
        handleSubmit : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //Validate entire form here
            var validForm = true;
            this.state.Fields.forEach(function(field){
                if (typeof field.isValid === "function") {
                    var validField = field.isValid(field.refs[field.props.name]);
                    console.log("validField "+validField);
                    validForm = validForm && validField;
                }
            });
            console.log("form"+validForm);
            //after validation complete post to server 
            if (validForm) {
                alert("ok");
             //pass data to server   
            axios.post("/register",
              {
                  full_name :this.state.strFullName,
                  email:this.state.strEmail,
                  password:this.state.strPassword,
                  phone_number:this.state.intPhoneNumber,

              }).then(function (response) {
                var data=response.data;
                alert("Email already exist");
              });
            }

             this.setState({
                 strFullName:'',
                 strEmail:'',
                 intPhoneNumber:'',
                 strPassword:''
              })

        },
render : function(){
        //Render form 
        return(
<MyInput type={'email'} 
                value={this.state.strEmail} 
                label={'Email'} 
                name={'Email'} 
                htmlFor={'Email'} 
                isrequired={true}
                onChange={this.onChangeEmail} 
                onComponentMounted={this.register} 
                strMessageRequired={'Please Enter Email.'}
                strMessageEmail={'Please Enter Correct Email'}  />
);
    }
});
module.exports=RegistrationForm;
```

MyInput Component is for validation.
MyInput.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var MyInput = React.createClass({
    //onchange event
    handleChange: function (e) {
        this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
        var isValidField = this.isValid(e.target);
    },
    //validation function
    isValid: function (input) {
if (input.getAttribute('type') == "email" && input.value != "") {
            if (!this.validateEmail(input.value)) {
                input.classList.add('error');
                input.nextSibling.textContent = this.props.strMessageEmail;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                input.classList.remove('error');
                input.nextSibling.textContent = "";
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the complete MyInput Component ?

Comment: You can do like to take a response from backend and print it
, as it is obvious of getting a response from backend

Comment: yes. i am getting response from backend.see in this axios.post("/register", {
 full_name :this.state.strFullName,
 email:this.state.strEmail,
              password:this.state.strPassword,
              phone_number:this.state.intPhoneNumber,
                            
          }).then(function (response) {
            var data=response.data;
            alert("Email already exist");
          });
        }

Comment: Hi there, I've improved the readability of your question and made the title a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (validForm) {
           alert("ok");
        var self=this; // put  

  
.
.
.
.
//instead of alert
this.setState({
   error:'Email Already exists'
})
```

This will render the parent component and then the MyInput component.
Then, You'll need to pass this as a prop to child component.

```
<MyInput type={'email'} 
                value={this.state.strEmail} 
                label={'Email'} 
                name={'Email'} 
                htmlFor={'Email'} 
                isrequired={true}
                onChange={this.onChangeEmail} 
                onComponentMounted={this.register} 
                strMessageRequired={'Please Enter Email.'}
                strMessageEmail={'Please Enter Correct Email'}  
                error={this.state.error || null} //new addition
/>
```

**This will render MyInput with another prop i.e. 'error'**

Now, in the render method of MyInput, you can handle it like:

```
if(!this.props.error){
   return (<div className="message">{this.props.error}</div>
}
```

***or use react conditional rendering if you want to display something in between.***

#### Edit for showing error

**Add this line above or below the input box**

```
{this.props.error > 0 &&
        <h2>
          {this.props.error} 
        </h2>
      }
```

Comment: thank you sir for helping me.Your answer is  technically correct sir.I tried this one.But it is not working.Where to put this--> if(!this.props.error){
   return (<div className="message">{this.props.error}</div>
}

Comment: This is just a example usecase. It needs to be put in the render function. Rest, **I can guide you only if I need the exact way in which you want to show this error**

Comment: it does not showing error message.I want when user entered emai-id then if same eamil -id is present then show error near to textbox of email-id

Comment: Just editied the answer, you can show the error with that. Refer to this link [Conditional Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) for more details.
**In short, if this.props.error exists then you have the error else not.**